# Fragment exitTransition overlaps enterTransition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

For animating Fragments, I want to declare the animation at runtime based on provided inputs. Because `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations` only uses static xml files, I am using `Fragment.setEnterTransition`, `Fragment.setExitTransition` (setCustomAnimations is not an option).

The problem I am having is that when performing a "forward" push animation, the incoming fragment is expected to slide over the outgoing fragment, and the outgoing fragment slides to the left (not fully, so the incoming one will overlap it). However, the exiting fragment is drawn on top of the incoming fragment:

[image]

For backwards navigation, this side effect provides the intended behaviour.

I believe this is an issue with `setCustomAnimations` as well, and [have seen a solution there to swap the top two views of the fragment container](https://github.com/airbnb/native-navigation/blob/9cf50bf9b751b40778f473f3b19fcfe2c4d40599/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/navigation/ScreenCoordinatorLayout.java#L43).

However, this method for some reason does not work with the Fragment transitions API.

Has anyone hit this issue and found a solution?

Comment: Was looking into it a bit more. If a transition extends `Visibility`, the disappearing view seemed to be added to the `ViewOverlay` of the sceneRoot. This means it would always be drawn last overtop all content: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/transition/Visibility.java#450. However, why this isn't configurable isn't clear to me. Perhaps the solution is not to use `Visibility` at all, but seems the ability to configure the order in which appearing/disappearing views are drawn is something the abstraction should provide.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I couldn't find a solution so I have created the following issue:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194808726

Hopefully they will do something about it.

Google recommends single-activity, fragments etc. Thats all fine and well, but it is unacceptable that simple use-cases like the one you have explained are just broken after all these years. No words for it.

Comment: Was looking into it a bit more- does your `Transition` extend `Visibility`? If it does, I suspect the reason why the disappearing view might always be overlaying is that Visibility seems to add the disappearing view to the `ViewOverlay` of the `sceneRoot`. This means it would always be drawn last overtop all content: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/transition/Visibility.java#450. However, why this isn't configurable isn't clear to me.

Comment: Yes, my Transition extend Visibility (Slide etc.).  I am no expert, but from what I have read so far (including your comment), it indeed looks like that any subclass of Visibility causes the problem. It seems the entering view isn't added to the overlay. Hence, it will be below. I first started to use FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations. However, the transition becomes weird when navigating back during the transition. The popExiting fragment will be below the popEntering fragment. SetEnterTransition and SetExitTransition don't seem to have this problem.